# “Five rewards in this year” vs “Five rewards this year”

Tags: sentence-construction, prepositions

How do I state the fact that **a person had or received a number of something** during this year? I need the sentence to be nominal, i.e. without a predicate. I see two ways of saying it (let’s take rewards as an example):

- Five rewards in this year
- Five rewards this year

Which way is more appropriate and sounds better?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using temporal adjuncts (extra bits of information at the end of the sentence about when something happened), we often use the prepositions *in, on* or *at* with a noun phrase afterwards:

- I will see you **on** Tuesday.
- It happened **in** the afternoon.
- **At** Christmas my parents came to stay.

However, when we use the words *this, that, next* or *last* with these nouns, we don't usually use another preposition:

- I will see you next Sunday.
- It happened that afternoon.
- Last Christmas my parents came to stay.
- *I will see you on next Sunday. (X)
- *It happened in that afternoon. (X)
- *At last Christmas my parents came to stay. (X)

We also don't usually use prepositions with time words that begin with *to-* or *yester-*. This may be because the prefixes *to-* and *yester-* mean something like *this* and *last*:

- *I'll see you on tomorrow. (X)
- *I saw him on yesterday. (X)
- *I'll see you at tonight. (X)

**The Original Poster's Question**

> She's won five rewards this year.
>
> She's won five rewards in this year. (X)

The first example is fine. The second one is awkward because it uses *in* and *this* together. If we didn't use *this* then we could use a preposition with the year:

- She won five awards *in* 2014.

For the Original Poster's verb-less phrase the best option is:

- Five results this year.

*Hope this is helpful!*

Comment: I agree with all you've written; but if we go on to modify the temporal adjunct, we can say "She has won five awards in this year *alone*."   She's a rising star.

Comment: @TRomano I agree. And probably not awkward at all if the adjunct is even longer: *in this calendar year alone*, for example :)